# Prime decomposition in cyclotomic field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm stuck in a problem stating as:

Let $p\ne q$ be odd primes.
Consider a field extension
$$\mathbb{Q}\subset K:=\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{(-1)^{\frac{q-1}{2}}\cdot q}\right)\subset L:=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{q})$$
where $K\subset L$ is supported by Gauss sum.

Now I have an assertion:

> $p$ splits completely in $K$ if and only if $p$ decomposes in $L$ into an even number of prime factors.

One side is obvious: the only if part.
But I don't know how to prove the other side.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$pO_L$ is unramified: $pO_L = \prod_{j=1}^{g_p} P_j$ where $f_p  = N(P_1)$ and $[L:\Bbb{Q}]=f_p g_p$.

Let $\sigma_p\in Gal(L/\Bbb{Q})$ be the automorphism whose reduction $\bmod P_1$ is the Frobenius, so that $f_p = order(\sigma_p)$,

Let $F=L^{\sigma_p}$ be the subfield fixed by $\sigma_p$, which is the largest subfield whose Frobenius at $P_1\cap O_F$ is trivial.

Since $F/\Bbb{Q}$ is Galois it is the largest subfield where $p$ splits completely.

We get that $[L:F]=order(\sigma_p)=f_p$ and $g_p=[F:\Bbb{Q}]$.

$L/\Bbb{Q}$ is cyclic so $K$ is the only quadratic subfield and $K\subset F$ iff $[F:\Bbb{Q}]$ is even.

Comment: The thought is correct and amazing. Thank you!